# Strange Shader Behaviour in GLES2

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Hey all Can you notice anything wrong in this code? it is straight from the book "Open GLES 2.0 Programming Guide" and I have been searching around for results and tackling the code changing things about etc. and it still wont work!! The result this code produces is attached via an image[image: Rectangle is shown when it should be a triangle]

Vertex Shader Code:

```
attribute vec4 v_Position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = v_Position;
}
```

Fragment Shader Code:

```
precision mediump float;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Finally my code: (note the shaders compile successfully so does the linking of the two shader programs into the program called 'shaderProgram')

```
GLfloat verts[] = {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f};
GLushort inds[] = {0,1,2};
GLuint ibo = 0;
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
////get the buffer object
glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
glGenBuffers(1,&ibo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,3*3,verts,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*3,inds,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLint vPos = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "v_Position");
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPos);
glVertexAttribPointer(vPos,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3,0);
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, vPos, "v_Position");


glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

glDeleteBuffers(1,&vbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1,&ibo);
```

Comment: I don't understand why `glVertexAttribPointer(vPos,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3,0);` It must be `glVertexAttribPointer(vPos,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems in the function
`glVertexAttribPointer(vPos,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3,0);`

The 5th parameter is the stride, while the last is the size. In this case you don't need it: It must be:
`glVertexAttribPointer(vPos,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0, nullptr);`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply,
This seems to of stopped anything from drawing and I am presented with the default glClear colour. Ive also tried setting the zPos to negative (and positive just encase) but still no results :(

Comment: I fixed it!!

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,3*3,verts,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

should of been

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,3*3*sizeof(GLfloat),verts,GL_STATIC_DRAW);